# 404 when downloading Evenote resources directly via web/http?

Tags: evernote

Up until a few days ago, the app I am developing was downloading Evernote resources directly over http fine, as per instructions here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php#downloading

It stopped working correctly however and after some investigating I used Postman to fire of a test request. This is the request:

```
POST /shard/s37/res/990ee009-fa0d-42cf-9d85-b13816af8c47 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.evernote.com
auth: S%3Ds84%3AU%3D8e847d%3AE%3D159c134s4e4%3AC%3D15269830808%3AP%3D185%3AA%3Dcstiaan84%3AV%3D2%3AH%3D16320957f0124a6bc1c53f526a04cdff
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a145643c-a626-e3e7-44f7-6ad5387f1df6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I know the url and the urlencoded auth token are correct because all other requests to the api work correctly.

Has anyone else came across this lately? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried it and it worked for me (my own note and auth, not yours). Is the note that contains that resource deleted, maybe? Try removing the Content-Type header?

Comment: Hm, strange. I see you work at Evernote. May I contact your directly to better exchange keys perhaps? If so, please let me know how.

Comment: The NoteStore.getResource method works without a problem with the exact same resource guid. The problem must be somewhere in constructing the url/request.

Comment: absolutely - email me at <snipped>

Comment: Awesome! Signing off now (GMT+1). Will contact you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the url for the resource was incorrect. Corstiaan was generating the url based on:

`user_store.getPublicUserInfo('someusername').webApiUrlPrefix`

and the url for different users is different (each shard in the Evernote service has a number of users, so different users can be on different shards). The username being passed in to getPublicUserInfo was incorrect, and so the webApiUrlPrefix was pointing to an incorrect shard, where the resource doesn't exist, thus causing a 404.

Comment: Thanks for your help @akhaku! One comment for people using Ruby: when encoding the auth token for the post request, use URI::encode(str) and not ERB::Util.url_encode as this does not gives the required output.